# how to match rtmp links

Tags: php, preg-match

How to match the following link structure that started with `rtmp://`

```
$link = "rtmp://00.000.000.000/live"; // GOOD
$link = "http://00.000.000.000/live"; // BAD
$link = "www.00.000.000.000/live"; // BAD
```

so only matching the links with `rtmp` with `preg_match` or whatever ~ thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do:

```
preg_match('~^rtmp://~', $link);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will suffice..

```
if(stripos($link,'rtmp://')!==false)
{
echo "Good";
}
```

Comment: What if the link contains `rtmp` somewhere else, perhaps at the end? I'd at least check for `rtmp://` :)

Comment: @AmalMurali, Agreed .. changed it . Tnx ^_^

Comment: Thanks both, it now work perfect after @Amal Murali suggestion.

Comment: @JackBen, Yeah Amal is an intelli PHP guy on SO. ^_^